# How to validate CronSequenceGenerator cron expressions?

Tags: java, spring, cron

How could I validate `cron` expressions that are prepared for use of `CronSequenceGenerator`?

I mean, I cannot wait until the cron executes automatically as I'm defining like monthly intervals.

Is the following correct? How can I be sure?

```
monthly at midnight: `0 0 0 1 * *`
monthly at 1 am: `0 0 1 1 * *`
weekly, on sunday at midnight: `0 0 0 * * SUN`
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Spring's [CronSequenceGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)
class has a method
[isValidExpression(String expression)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html#isValidExpression-java.lang.String-)
which takes the cron expression and returns a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you are ok with quartz api then you should use org.quartz.CronExpression.isValidExpression(String s)

Api ref http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html

Comment: Ok but still this doesn't tell me if the cron expression is what I initially wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I prefer to directly use `"new CronSequenceGenerator(cronExpression)"` instead of the static method `isValidExpression`.
Doing the new directly gives you a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentExpression` with a message telling you where the problem lies.

Unfortunately `"isValidExpression"` chokes the exception and simply returns false.